# How to activate Payara class loading parameter fish.payara.classloading.delegate?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, classloader, payara

I have Guava class loading issues and can resolve all issues by adding a `glassfish-web.xml` as stated in the [official documentation](https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/content/documentation/extended-documentation/classloading.html#42-war-files).

However I don't want to add a not backward compatible `glassfish-web.xml` (deployment on Glassfish 3.1.2.2 is not working) and activate this class loading within Payara 162 itself as stated in the [official documentation](https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/content/documentation/extended-documentation/classloading.html#41-globally-override-payara-included-libraries) and the [blog article to release 162](http://blog.payara.fish/whats-new-in-payara-server-162).

I didn't find an exact specification on how to set this system property and as no way is working currently I simply tried all individually.

1. jvm-option

   - `asadmin create-jvm-options --target server-config -Dfish.payara.classloading.delegate=false`
2. system property

   - `asadmin create-system-properties --target domain fish.payara.classloading.delegate=false`
   - `asadmin create-system-properties --target server fish.payara.classloading.delegate=false`
   - `asadmin create-system-properties --target server-config fish.payara.classloading.delegate=false`
   - all three system property targets together

None of this ways worked.

Comment: These two methods should both work. When you start Payara, could you run `jps -v` against it to get a list of all the arguments used against it when it starts? You should get something that starts with something like `27239 ASMain -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:MaxPermSize=192m......`and there should be the classloading.delegate property in there.

Comment: I checked that and it is not. These are 5 methods splitted in two approaches. I'm using currently the last one (all together). Why is that not listed in `jps -v` and how is the correct way?

Comment: Could this be related to `default-config`? I thought this has to go to `server-config`, but probably it has to go to `default-config`?

Comment: No, it should go in the `server-config`. The easiest way to find out how to do this would be to use the admin console after turning on the asadmin command recorder. There is a button in the top right to start and stop it and it will output the asadmin commands which correspond to the changes you make. https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/content/documentation/extended-documentation/asadmin-recorder.html

Comment: (do be aware that the admin console will use an asadmin command to remove **all** the JVM options first, then reapply them all. So you would need to pick out the one you need)

Comment: Why should the command recorder do something special? I could also set this via GUI, but it simply does not work. I checked the Payara sources and it looks like the Logger `javax.enterprise.system.core` would log if the `CommonClassLoader` is not instantiated (Skipping creation of CommonClassLoader), but there is no log output, i.e. it looks like there is a bug in my situation and Guava is still loaded from Payara instead of WAR, although the parameter is active. Are you sure this parameter would appear in `jps -v`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature, not a bug :(

As mentioned by the developer it is intended for WARs to not obey the global system setting. The only way to achieve this for WARs is to add the configuration in the glassfish-web.xml.

https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/1249